# Como fazer um alert em php

Tags: php

Da para fazer um alert ou outro tipo de mensagem após o usuário errar a senha na pagina de login por exemplo ? tentei fazer desta maneira:

```
    unset ($_SESSION['login']);
unset ($_SESSION['senha']);
header('location:index.html');
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("Erro ao fazer Login")';
echo '</script>';
```

mas não funcionou, ele volta pra tela, mas nao da alert algum

Comment: A sua linha `header("Location")` redireciona o usuário para a página `index.html` e todo o ressto do código será ignorado pelo navegador. Se a intenção é mostrar o alerta e não redirecionar, retire essa linha.

Comment: Inclusive, é bom eliminar totalmente o alert. Ponha um intervalo de tempo no location, como solução provisória. <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/">, assim seu alert continua intrusivo (como todo alert) mas funciona

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Envie parâmetros com query string para index.html e em index adicione o script de alert.

```
<?php
unset ($_SESSION['login']);
unset ($_SESSION['senha']);
header('location:index.html?info=error&msg=1');
```

E em `index.html` adicione o script:

```
<script>
    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    if(getParameterByName('info') === 'error' && getParameterByName('msg') === '1') {
        alert('Erro ao fazer Login');
    }
</script>
```

A função `getParameterByName` foi extraída daqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

O seu código não executa porque ao redirecionar a página com o header location no PHP o código abaixo em javascript não é executado pelo navegador

Comment: Funcionou, mas achei bem complexo, e n entendi esse script para pegar a url da pagina

Comment: Quando você redireciona o javascript recupera as variáveis na url, pesquise sobre expressões regulares (é a parte magia negra), isso sempre confunde mesmo, mas o que importa mesmo é você entender o que aconteceu, PHP não executa javascript ele encaminha para o browser do cliente executar, o que fizemos foi apenas encaminhar variáveis para o javascript tratá-las e exibir o `alert` ou não.